# How does the BINDING variable identifies the correct XML for my Android APP Screen using Java and Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, binding, android-viewbinding

My questions is relatively simple: How does the binding find the layout to my Main Actvity since I don't use the ID, I use the name "root". And how am I going to find different layouts to my other screens using the similar code?

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        var binding: ActivityMainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) // variable binding to access layout views
        setContentView(binding.root) // here define o XML
    }
}
```

I'm new to view binding. I haven't found a good resource to study it yet.

Comment: You inflate the "binding" that has all of the references but `setContentView` needs some `View` to use. Preferably the `root` of the binding. By returning the root, you are not losing the binding instance of the references. Is that what you meant? I am not sure what you mean by different layouts.

Comment: I mean, if I have different xml for the screens, how does the code know which one to load if I'm not calling a specific ID? Using Java we had the setcontentview  and we could choose the name of the xml, but in this example I'm not using the name, I'm using "root".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ActivityMainBinding` is not named `ActivityMainBinding` because you use it in the `MainActivity`. It's generated based on a layout file that is named `activity_main` so technically you are using specific ID but not via layout resource.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    var binding: ActivityMainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
}
```

is exactly the same as:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
```

without the utility of data binding ofc.

Once you have a layout that uses data binding structure, the binding is automatically generated. e.g. for layout `activity_second` there will be `ActivitySecondBinding`.

Comment: Really? hahah that's funny! I will try with another class and if it works I will check your answer as my solution. Thank you! :D